# VBA to push data into a database

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I have a data table that has just a few columns: GLID, Metric Category, Amount, and Metric Date. The way the data is organized on the excel file I need to use is like a matrix as so:
[image]

The date columns are the metric date and the numbers below them are the amounts. As you can see for each date there is some amount that pertains to a particular metric category and in some cases a GLID. Now what I need to do in VBA is push the data into the format as so

```
GLID       Metric Category         Amount          Metric Date
5500       Property Tax-5500        -8               3/31/2020
5500       Property Tax-5500        -8               4/30/2020
```

So on and so forth. I am completely new to VBA so this particular task is daunting and challenging for me and thus why I made a post here. If anyone has some suggestions I would greatly appreciate it.

So far this is the setup I have in VBA:

```
Sub second_export()
Dim sSQL As String, sCnn As String, sServer As String
    Dim db As Object, rs As Object
    sServer = "CATHCART"
    sCnn = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=Portfolio_Analytics;Data Source=" & sServer & ";" & _
              "Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;"

    Set db = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    If db.State = 0 Then db.Open sCnn




End Sub
```

**Note For Further Clarification:**

The number of columns is 36 and the number of rows is 46 in the excel file. For the categories that do not have a GLID then we can push NULL if needed.

I can push data into the database when its simply and insert but I have to pivot the data such that the GLID and Metric category are repeated for their associated dates and amounts.

Comment: Your spreadsheet shows -$8 for 55000 in 31/3/2020 but you want to push 500 into database with a GLID of 5500 ?. You need to specify the schema for the table in the database, field types, primary keys etc ? Do the lines without GLID need to be pushed. How big is the spreadsheet max rows and max columns ?

Comment: @CDP1802 Apologies I was just trying to show an example. The number of columns is 36 and the number of rows is 46 in the excel file.

Comment: *Specifically* which part of this are you having a problem with ?  Unpivoting your data, adding a record to your database or ???  Can you insert a record with fixed values?  Maybe try that first.

Comment: @TimWilliams I can push data into the database when its simply and insert but I have to pivot the data such that the GLID and Metric category are repeated for their associated dates and amounts. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes and it would help your question to have added that - right now people are trying to guess exactly what the problem is...

Comment: @TimWilliams Thank you, added for further clarification. I hope as the question stands it is a bit more clear now.

Comment: Do you need help with the database inserts ?

Comment: @CDP1802 Yes I do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create a sheet of data to upload

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub CreateDataSheet()

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, wsData As Worksheet, header As Variant
    Dim iLastRow, iLastCol, dt As Variant, iOutRow
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1") ' the matrix sheet
    Set wsData = wb.Sheets("Sheet2") ' sheet to hold table data

    wsData.Cells.Clear
    wsData.Range("A1:D1") = Array("GLID", "Metric Category", "Amount", "Metric Date")

    ' get header
    iLastCol = ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    iLastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    header = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 3), ws.Cells(1, iLastCol))
    'Debug.Print iLastRow, iLastCol, UBound(header, 2)

    Dim r, c
    iOutRow = 2
    For r = 2 To iLastRow
        For c = 1 To UBound(header, 2)
            'Debug.Print r, header(1, c), ws.Cells(r, c + 2)
            With wsData.Cells(iOutRow, 1)
                .Offset(0, 0) = ws.Cells(r, 1)
                .Offset(0, 1) = ws.Cells(r, 2)
                .Offset(0, 2) = ws.Cells(r, c + 2)
                .Offset(0, 3) = header(1, c)
            End With
            iOutRow = iOutRow + 1
        Next
    Next
    wsData.Range("A1").Select
    MsgBox iOutRow - 2 & " Rows created on " & wsData.Name, vbInformation

End Sub
```

Then create a table in the database

```vb
Sub CreateTable()

    Const TABLE_NAME = "dbo.GL_TEST"
    Dim SQL As String, con As Object

    SQL = "CREATE TABLE " & TABLE_NAME & "( " & vbCr & _
          "RECNO int NOT NULL," & vbCr & _
          "GLID nchar(10)," & vbCr & _
          "METRICNAME nvarchar(255)," & vbCr & _
          "AMOUNT money," & vbCr & _
          "METRICDATE date," & vbCr & _
          "PRIMARY KEY (RECNO))"

     'Debug.Print sql
     Set con = mydbConnect()
     'con.Execute ("DROP TABLE " & TABLE_NAME) ' use during testing
     con.Execute SQL
     con.Close
     Set con = Nothing

     MsgBox "Table " & TABLE_NAME & " created"

End Sub
```

using data connection.

```vb
Function mydbConnect() As Object
    Dim sConStr As String

    Const sServer = "CATHCART"
    sConStr = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;" & _
              "Integrated Security=SSPI;" & _
              "Persist Security Info=True;" & _
              "Initial Catalog=Portfolio_Analytics;" & _
              "Data Source=" & sServer & ";" & _
              "Use Procedure for Prepare=1;" & _
              "Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;"

    Set mydbConnect = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    mydbConnect.Open sConStr

End Function
```

Then load the data from the sheet one record at a time with auto-commit off.

```vb
Sub LoadData()

    Const TABLE_NAME = "dbo.GL_TEST"

    Dim SQL As String
    SQL = " INSERT INTO " & TABLE_NAME & _
          " (RECNO,GLID,METRICNAME,AMOUNT,METRICDATE) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?) "

    Dim con As Object, cmd As Object, rs As Variant
    Set con = mydbConnect()
    Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

    With cmd
        .ActiveConnection = con
        .CommandType = adCmdText
        .CommandText = SQL
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("P1", adInteger, adParamInput)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("P2", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 10)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("P3", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 255)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("P4", adCurrency, adParamInput)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("P5", adDate, adParamInput)
    End With

    con.Execute "SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON"

    Dim ws As Worksheet, iLastRow As Long, i As Long
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2") ' sheet were table data is
    iLastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To iLastRow
        cmd.Parameters(0).Value = i
        cmd.Parameters(1).Value = ws.Cells(i, 1)
        cmd.Parameters(2).Value = ws.Cells(i, 2)
        cmd.Parameters(3).Value = ws.Cells(i, 3)
        cmd.Parameters(4).Value = ws.Cells(i, 4)
        cmd.Execute
    Next

    con.Execute "COMMIT"
    con.Execute "SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF"

    rs = con.Execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " & TABLE_NAME)
    MsgBox rs(0) & " Rows are in " & TABLE_NAME, vbInformation

    con.Close
    Set con = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, I do have a sheet in excel already as well as the database. Would the last part of your code be the only thing I really need to look at?

Comment: @justaneweb Yes, adjust the SQL to use your fields names and the correct number of ? placeholders. In the cmd append 1 parameter for each ? in the correct order using the appropriate field type. Then in the final loop assign a value to each parameter from the sheet. I suggest you get it working with my example first before trying to change it for yours.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you can loop over your data:

```vb
Sub Tester()

    Dim rw As Range, n As Long
    Dim GLID, category, dt, amount

    For Each rw In ActiveSheet.Range("H2:AS47").Rows 

        'fixed per-row
        GLID = Trim(rw.Cells(1).Value)
        category = Trim(rw.Cells(2).Value)

        'loopover the date columns
        For n = 3 To rw.Cells.Count

            dt = rw.Cells(n).EntireColumn.Cells(1).Value 'date from Row 1
            amount = rw.Cells(n).Value

            Debug.Print rw.Cells(n).Address, GLID, category, amount, dt

            'insert a record using your 4 values
            'switch GLID to null if empty

        Next n
    Next rw

End Sub
```

Comment: The range "A2:AJ46" for my case would that entail all of the data I am trying to iterate through i.e.H1:AS47

Comment: Yes if that's where it is then use that  - you don't need the first row if your data has headers though.  Thr range should span your data: including the two fixed columns and the additional date columns

Comment: The only headers are GLID, and Metric Category but I would need the dates which are parallel to those headers.

Comment: Yes but you don't need to loop over the header row.  If the dates are in Row1 the code will fetch them from there.

Comment: I see I included the range without the headers but when I do Debug.Print dt my starting date is 8/31/2020 and it should be 3/31/2020.

Comment: The third cell in range H2:AS2 (your first `rw` range)  should be J2.  Try adding Debug.Print `rw.Cells(n).Address` and make sure.

Comment: Where do I add the print part? I put in the second for loop and it started at AA for some reason

Comment: Hey Tim, any idea how to circumvent the insert of 1000 rows restriction?

Comment: What restriction?  Remember I have on idea of what you're doing outside of what you already posted.

Comment: So since I am trying to insert values into a sql table. There is a max amount of inserts allowed apparently of 1000 for the version of sql I am using, does that make sense?

Comment: **How** are you inserting the records though?  If you're trying to do it all in one single statement then maybe you can't do that.  I don't know anything about SQL server, but a quick google gave me this for example: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/de08f983-2a7c-4eb8-8052-1678b6531f5f/insert-more-than-1000-rows?forum=transactsql  If you can add more details to your question then someone might have a useful suggestion as to how you can change your approach.